# How was frequency measured in Evenson, et al.'s paper on the measurement of the speed of light?

Tags: speed-of-light, laser, frequency

To avoid confusion, please note that I am referring to a paper published before the speed of light was defined axiomatically. I am referring to [this paper](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.29.1346), but I don't understand it.

In the abstract, they say that the wavelength of their laser was determined using interferometry. This makes sense. But how did they measure the frequency of their laser?

Comment: I think they did it here , https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.1654607 , reference 8 on the paper you quote